# How to disable FormControl in FormArray in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I wrote the below code snippet, which I considered as it will disable the `FormControl` in a `FormArray`.

**some.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
    <div *ngFor="let num of countArr">
        <input type="text" formNameArray="arrs">
    </div>
</form>
```

**some.component.ts**

```
countArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
count = 5;
arrs;
testForm: FormGroup;

this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group(
    arrs: this.formBuilder.array([])
);

this.arrs = this.testForm.get('arrs');

for (let i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
    this.arrs.insert(i, new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}));
}
```

But after `for` execution completed, I checked the form and found nothing has been disabled. Can you please tell me where I am doing wrong??? :-)

Thank you for your help!!! :-)

Comment: Maybe it's because you're using `formNameArray` instead of [`formArrayName`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName).

Comment: are you trying to create dynamic input box with disable ?

Comment: @ChellappanV yes I am trying to create dynamic input box with disable

Comment: the why are you looping counterArr instead of your formNameArray

Comment: @ChellappanV sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: can you share your code in stackblitz

Answer (score 6):

First of all, this is how your html component should look like:

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
    <div formArrayName="arrs">
        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let arrItem of testForm.get('arrs').controls; let i = index">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

You do not need to iterate some random **count** variable inside your html component. You can iterate your added controls.

You may ask "Which controls exactly? They are not added yet!"

Well, this is why you programatically add those controls in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.testForm = new FormGroup({
      arrs: new FormArray([])
    }
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
      const control = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
      (<FormArray>this.testForm.get('arrs')).push(control);
    }

    this.disableInputs();
}
```

This is the corrent syntax to initiate the `FormArray` and then create an initial control inside the `for` loop and push the newly created control to your array.

Note: there is a `disableInputs()` function call. This is where you disable your inputs programatically as well:

```
  disableInputs() {
    (<FormArray>this.testForm.get('arrs'))
      .controls
      .forEach(control => {
        control.disable();
      })
  }
```

A working sample: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4seudv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enable Dynamic Input enable

```
form: FormGroup;
  orders = [
    { id: 100, name: 'order 1' },
    { id: 200, name: 'order 2' },
    { id: 300, name: 'order 3' },
    { id: 400, name: 'order 4' }
  ];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    const controls = this.orders.map(c => new FormControl(''));

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      orders: new FormArray(controls)
    });

    this.form.get('orders').controls
      .forEach(control => {
        control.disable();
      })
  }
```

and html should look like this

```
<form [formGroup]="form" >
  <label formArrayName="orders" *ngFor="let order of form.controls.orders.controls; let i = index">
    <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
    {{orders[i].name}}
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use formArray control in the iteration to assign it in each input:

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
    <div formArrayName="arrs">
        <div *ngFor="let num of countArr; let idx = index">
            <input type="text" [formControlName]="idx" [attr.disabled]="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

You can refer to this article:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#display-the-formarray

Comment: Prachi, thank you for your answer, but I want to disable each formcontrol, how can I do that?

Comment: I have updated the code for disabling. Don't go for complex logic for simple functionality.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the FormControls of a FormArray, "reset" makes it easy.

```
this.formGroupHere.get(['formArrayHere']).reset({
        disableFields: {
            formControlHere: true,
            otherFormControl: true
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by disabling the formControl while initialization or updating as below:

I assume that, `testForm` is the `formGroupName` , `arrs` is the `FormArrayName` and `inputValue` is the `formControlName`

```
(<FormArray>this.testForm.get('arrs')).push(new FormGroup({
  'inputValue': new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
}));
```

You have to remember that disabling the form input will not allow you to submit. Instead, you can use the `readonly` property as below.

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" />
```

This will help you get the input values from the form as well.

Source for [readonly](https://blog.netgloo.com/2014/05/31/disabling-an-input-field-in-a-form-and-sending-data/)